# Is there a way to save output into an array after a program has been executed?

Tags: java, arrays, permutation

I figured out how to generate permutations of a set using recursion, however I cannot figure out how to save the values it produces. Is there a way to re scan over data outputted by the program in order to save it? Or am I going the wrong direction here?

Here is the code I've been working with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class test
{
    //Arrays.toString(int[]); >>Converts int array to string.
    //int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");
    public static void main()
    {
        String str;
        str = getStr();
        //
        int n = str.length();
        //Trying to use this to catch output!!
        int nf = 1;
        for(int i=n;i>0;i--)
        {nf *= i;}
        int[][] array = new int[nf][n];
        //
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {visited[i] = false;}
        char[] branch = new char[n];
        generatePermutations(arr,n,branch,-1,visited);
        //The visited array keeps track of which nodes have been visited already.
    }

    public static void generatePermutations(char[] arr,int size,char[] branch,int level,boolean[] visited)
    {
        if(level >= size-1)
        {System.out.println(branch);
         return;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            if(!visited[i])
            {
                branch[++level] = arr[i];
                visited[i] = true;
                generatePermutations(arr,size,branch,level,visited);
                visited[i] = false;
                level--;
            }
        }
    }
    //
    public static String getStr()
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter the size (n): ");
        n = kb.nextInt();
        int[] initialSet = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            initialSet[i] = (i+1);
        }
        str = Arrays.toString(initialSet).replace(", ", "").replace("[","").replace("]","");
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you output the data, also save it to a file.

Comment: You don't have a formal `main` method.  You have one that's *called* `main`, but it isn't `main`.

Comment: It looks like you want to replace `System.out.println(branch)` with code that stores the result into an array.  Look into [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).